# Basic Swift SpriteKit Collisions using PhysicsBodys

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

**The problem:** I seem to be having a little trouble getting my player to collide with a coin, and adding +1 to a coinLabel upon the collision. The player should continue moving after coming in contact with the coin.

**What I have now:** With the code I have now, the player travels through the coin, but there is no collision that takes place and +1 isn't added to the coin label.

I am still learning the swift language, so I appreciate any help that is given.

Code:

```
struct ColliderType {

static let playerCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0

static let boundary: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
​  
​static let coinCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
​
​static let bodyA: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
​
​static let bodyB: UInt32 = 0x1 << 8

}

​override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
​
var coinInt = 0
​
​
​
​self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -7.0)
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
player.zPosition = 1
player.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width / 5.12)
player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

self.addChild(player)

generateCoins()

​
​
coin = SKSpriteNode( imageNamed: "coin")
coin.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: coin.size.height / 10)
coin.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
coin.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
coin.zPosition = 1
​self.addChild(coin)
​
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.playerCategory
​player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.boundary
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.coinCategory | ColliderType.boundary

coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.coinCategory
coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.playerCategory
coin.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.playerCategory

func didPlayerCollideWithCoin(player: SKSpriteNode, coin: SKSpriteNode) {



self.coin.removeFromParent()

self.coin += 1

coinLabel.text = "\(coinInt)"

}

​
​    
​
​func generateCoins()  {

if(self.actionForKey("spawning") != nil){return}

let coinTimer = SKAction.waitForDuration(7, withRange: 2)

let spawnCoin = SKAction.runBlock {

self.coin = SKSpriteNode( imageNamed: "coin")

self.coin.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.coin.size.height / 10)

self.coin.name = "coin"

self.coin.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

self.coin.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

var coinPosition = Array<CGPoint>()

coinPosition.append((CGPoint(x:340, y:103)))

coinPosition.append((CGPoint(x:340, y:148)))

coinPosition.append((CGPoint(x:340, y:218)))

coinPosition.append((CGPoint(x: 340, y:343)))

let spawnLocation =     coinPosition[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coinPosition.count)))]

let action = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveToX(+self.xScale, duration: 4.4))

self.coin.runAction(action)

self.coin.position = spawnLocation

self.addChild(self.coin)

print(spawnLocation)

}

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([coinTimer, spawnCoin])

self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence), withKey: "spawning")

}
​​
func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact)  {

let bodyA: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA

let bodyB: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

if ((bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.playerCategory) &&     (bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.coinCategory)){

didPlayerCollideWithCoin(bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode, coin: bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode)

}
    ​        
​}
```

Comment: Why `(circleOfRadius: coinOne.size.height / 10)` shouldn't it be `(circleOfRadius: coinOne.size.height / 2)` ?

Comment: I thought that the number that comes after the " / " controls how large the physicsBody is? Like if you use   / 2,  or /3 the physicsBody will be larger compared to using a higher number. I could be wrong.

Comment: The radius (which is what you're after) is the diameter/2. If the height of your coin == the coin's diameter (which it probably does) then this value divided by 2 probably gives you the size you're after.

Comment: Make sure you're clear about whether or not your want collisions, contacts or both.  I suspect you want the player and the coin to contact but not to collide?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I would like the player and coin to contact but not collide.

Comment: @nickfalk, Thank you for that information, that is the size that I am trying to achieve however the physicsBody for the coin doesn't seem to show up when viewing the physicsBodys of the sprite nodes.

Comment: I'm guessing that `coinOne` is nil, so that the radius will be 0 no matter what. A Circle with a radius of 0 isn't particularly visible.

Comment: Ok, I found and solved the issue of the coin physicsBody not appearing. It makes sense for the radius to be / 2, but when I use that value the physicsBody appears to be much larger than the coin itself, and the physicsBody seems to appear right below the coin itself when the coin spawns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift SpriteKit basic Contact / Collision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654854/swift-spritekit-basic-contact-collision)

Comment: @Alexander: Actually that's the duplicate... same questioner, same code, even the same answer regarding contacts vs. collisions.

Comment: @rebusB you are right. But the Answers are different

Comment: which is why the double posting is a problem... that answer is fairly similar but with different formatting and explanation. They should both be in the same place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try leaving your contactTestBitmasks the same but remove the collisionBitmasks between the player and coin:

```
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.playerCategory
​player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.boundary
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.boundary


coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.coinCategory
coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.playerCategory
```

This way, when the player collides with a coin it will register, but it wont "bounce off" and will continue moving in the same direction.

*Note: Using this MAY require you to use the

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
```

method instead of

```
func didPlayerCollideWithCoin(player: SKSpriteNode, coin: SKSpriteNode) {
```

But I recommend trying it with the didPlayerCollideWithCoin() method first.

In case you need it, it is implemented like this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
  firstBody = contact.bodyA
  secondBody = contact.bodyB
} else {
 firstBody = contact.bodyB
 secondBody = contact.bodyA
}

if firstBody.categoryBitMask == playerCategory &&   secondBody.categoryBitMask == coinCategory {
print("Your player passes through the coin")
score = score + 1
}
}
```

For more details see this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123393/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-sprite-kit-and-swift

Comment: Hi hb22, thank you for your answer! I edited my code to match what you had wrote in your response(tried it first with didPlayerCollideWithCoin, then tried the didBeginContact) but nothing had changed. So I used `view.showsPhysics = true` to check the physicsBodys and I noticed that the player physicsBody is visible but the physicsBody for the coin doesn't seem to appear, even though I have the coin node set up with a physicsBody of its' own. I think that might be the issue preventing the collision to function properly.